# how to pass a void function to an overrided OutlineButton class in order to work as onPressed property

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to pass pressed function to class MyOutlineButton in order to use it for onPressed which is the on of optional properties of OutilineButton widget but when i pass the pressed void function to MyOutlineButton class i can't see any changes on the screen ...
i expect when i click on play Button app play the specified song.
i don'n know whether I'm clear or not
please help me .

here is the code :

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
void main() => runApp(ExampleApp());

class ExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: App(),
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {

   @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    void pressed = () {
      setState(() {
        assetsAudioPlayer.open(
          Audio("assets/audio/ebi.mp3"),
        );
        assetsAudioPlayer.play();
        print("oh yeah!");
      });
    };
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: MyOutlineButton(text: "play",onPress: () => pressed,),
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MyOutlineButton extends StatefulWidget {
  MyOutlineButton(
      {this.text, this.onPress, this.hover, this.focus, this.splash, this.highlight, this.textColor});

  final String text;
  final void onPress;
  final Color splash;
  final Color highlight;
  final Color focus;
  final Color hover;
  final Color textColor;
  @override
  _MyOutlineButtonState createState() => _MyOutlineButtonState();
}

class _MyOutlineButtonState extends State<MyOutlineButton>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("hello");
    return OutlineButton(
      textColor: widget.textColor,
      highlightColor: widget.highlight,
      splashColor: widget.splash,
      focusColor: widget.focus,
      hoverColor: widget.hover,
      child: Text(widget.text,),
      //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.blue
      ),
      onPressed: () => widget.onPress,
    );
  }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put braces after `pressed`, it should be like this;

```
MyOutlineButton(text: "play",onPress: () => pressed(),)
```

or easier;

```
MyOutlineButton(text: "play",onPress: pressed,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need set your function to button. You are doing this:

```dart
onPressed: () => widget.onPress
```

But this not work, because you are not "invoking" the function, has two ways to do this:

```dart
onPressed: () => widget.onPress?.call()
```

or

```dart
onPressed: widget.onPress
```